# Optimality of Exponent in $\ell^{2}$ Decoupling Theorem

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

For $\delta>0$, let $\mathcal{N}_{\delta}$ denote the $\delta$-neighborhood of the truncated paraboloid $P^{n-1}$ and let $\theta$ denote a $\delta^{1/2}\times\cdots\times\delta^{1/2}\times\delta$ slab of $\mathcal{N}_{\delta}$ of the form
$$\theta=\{(\xi_{1},\ldots,\xi_{n-1},\eta+\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\xi_{j}^{2} : (\xi_{1},\ldots,(\xi_{n-1})\in C_{\theta}, |\eta|\leq 2\delta\}$$
where
$C_{\theta}=c+[-\frac{\delta^{1/2}}{2},\frac{\delta^{1/2}}{2}]^{n-1}$ for $c\in \frac{\delta^{1/2}}{2}\mathbb{Z}^{n-1}\cap [-1/2,1/2]^{n-1}$. For $\theta$, $f_{\theta}$ denote Fourier restriction of $f$ to $\theta$.

In the paper *[The Proof of the $\ell^{2}$ Decoupling Conjecture](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.5335v3.pdf)*, Bourgain and Demeter prove the inequality ((2) in their paper)

$$\|f\|_{p}\lesssim_{\epsilon}\delta^{-\frac{n-1}{4}+\frac{n+1}{2p}-\epsilon}(\sum_{\theta}\|f_{\theta}\|_{p}^{2})^{1/2} \tag{1}$$

for all $f$ with $\mathrm{supp}(\widehat{f})\subset\mathcal{N}_{\delta}$, where $p\geq\frac{2(n+1)}{n-1}$.

Just below (2) on pg. 2, the authors write that "...up to the $\delta^{-\epsilon}$ term, the exponent of $\delta$ is optimal, referring to a paper of [Garrigos and Seeger](https://www.math.wisc.edu/~seeger/papers/gs-esc-cm.pdf) for a "standard construction" to show this. I looked at the Garrigos, Seeger paper but couldn't find the cited argument.

It seems, though, that this optimality can be seen as follows. Set $f=\sum_{\theta}\psi_{\theta}^{\vee}$, where $\psi_{\theta}$ is a bump function adapted to $\theta$ (all implicit constants will be independent of $\theta$). Since $|\sum_{\theta}\psi_{\theta}^{\vee}(0)|\sim \delta^{-\frac{n-1}{2}}\delta^{\frac{n+1}{2}}$, it follows from continuity that $|\sum_{\theta}\psi_{\theta}^{\vee}(x)|\sim \delta^{-\frac{n-1}{2}}\delta^{\frac{n+1}{2}}$ on a ball of radius $\sim 1$ centered at the origin. Whence,

$$\|f\|_{p}\gtrsim \delta^{-\frac{n-1}{2}}\delta^{\frac{n+1}{2}} \tag{2}$$

But $\|f_{\theta}\|_{p}\sim\delta^{\frac{n+1}{2}-\frac{n+1}{2p}}$ for all $\theta$, whence $(\sum_{\theta}\|f_{\theta}\|_{p}^{2})^{1/2}\sim\delta^{-\frac{n-1}{4}+\frac{n+1}{2}-\frac{n+1}{2p}}$. Comparing with (2), we get the $\delta^{-\frac{n-1}{4}+\frac{n+1}{2p}}$ factor.

Perhaps this is asking for a mind reader, but is the preceding akin to the aforementioned standard construction?

Comment: I think Bourgain and Demeter are referring to the construction on page 180 of Garrigos-Seeger starting with "By a randomization argument...".

Comment: @TerryTao: Thank you for your comment. If the $\ell^{2}$ decoupling inequality holds with exponent $\alpha(p)$, then I only how see that that argument, adapting to the $\ell^{2}$ decoupling setting, shows $\alpha(p)\geq 0$.

Comment: Ah, I see; G-S are giving just one of the two standard examples.  The one you list in your question is the other.  (The earlier papers of Wolff should have both constructions, albeit for the cone instead of the paraboloid.)